# "Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not" when bootstrapping multiple components in Angular 5, but it kind of works?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-bootstrap

So I'm experiencing a very, very weird issue. I am trying to bootstrap multiple components in my Angular 5 project, so I can simply do:

```
<body>
    <awesome-component></awesome-component>
    <cool-component></cool-component>
</body>
```

It works fine, but there's an issue: **I cannot build the project with multiple modules in my `main.ts` file, except when I `ng build --watch` and add the second module afterwards**. This is extremely weird.

Take a look at these two modules:

**AwesomeModule**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AwesomeComponent } from "./awesome.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AwesomeComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    bootstrap: [AwesomeComponent]
})
export class AwesomeModule {}
```

**CoolComponent**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { CoolComponent } from "./cool.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [CoolComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    bootstrap: [CoolComponent]
})
export class CoolModule {}
```

If I bootstrap these inside `main.ts` like this:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AwesomeModule);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CoolModule);
```

I get this error when running `ng build`:

```
ERROR in Error: Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.
    at Object.resolveEntryModuleFromMain (C:\test\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\entry_resolver.js:121:15)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (C:\test\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:241:54)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

If I remove one of them like this:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AwesomeModule);
// platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CoolModule);
```

and I run `ng build` again, it works just fine. **Here is the weird part**: If I add `--watch` to `ng build`, it will listen for file changes and build the files affected. If I run `ng build --watch` with **ONE** module, it works fine (as I said before), but if I then add in the second module (remove the comment), it builds and works just fine.

So the issue is, I simply cannot get it to build from scratch with `ng build`, while I have two modules (with two components) in my `main.ts` file.

Anyone else experienced this issue before? Did I mess up something?

Here's one of my components just for good measure:

**cool.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "cool-component",
    templateUrl: "./cool.component.html"
})
export class CoolComponent {
    public title = "Cool stuff";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

from https://angular.io/guide/architecture
"bootstrap - the main application view, called the root component, that hosts all other app views. Only the root module should set this bootstrap property."

you can make a app-root and put in the html of this app-root

```
//index.html
<body>
<app-root>
</body>

//app-root.component.html
<awesome-component></awesome-component>
<cool-component></cool-component>
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid the `<app-root>` component all together. This is a "new" feature in Angular 4 or Angular 5 (not sure if 4 implemented this).

Comment: Sorry, I've never listened about this characteristic. The link I've write is the actual manual of Angular

Comment: But that is not the case. Check this out: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15668 - It was implemented in Angular 5, so I don't have to do what you want me to do.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know it, I'm sorry I can not help you

Comment: No problem, feel free to remove your answer  :)